# JS - Calling function from function not working

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that gets called, and in it, I call another function called:

```
updatePerson(name)
```

For some reason it never activates when the function below is called. Everything else in the function works.

```
  function updateName(name) {
    $.get('XXX',function (data) {
            var results = $.parseJSON(data);
            var matchName = String(results.data[0].first_name);
            updatePerson(matchName);}       
      ); 
  };
```

Has anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong?

If I run `alert(matchName)` I get Nick as a response.

If I run `console.log(updateMap(matchAddress))` I get undefined

Comment: paste the content of updatePerson also check on console and see if there are any errors

Comment: Good idea (sorry new to JS), ill give it a go now!

Comment: It calls it. You can test that by putting a `console.log('test');` in the beginning of your function `updatePerson` if it passes there. The problem is probably inside the function. Check also the console of your navigator for errors.

Comment: Hi, test works, but something is wrong with the argument I am sending as it coming through there as undefined (I have edited my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could do with the fact that you're passing a parameter from a callback function. In Javascript, variables inside a Callback are not available outside the callback. 
Try setting the value of String(results.data[0].first_name) to a variable declared outside of the updateName function (i.e a global variable) and then call the updatePerson function outside of update name, with the globally declared variable as a parameter. Like so

```js
  var globalMatchName = '';
  
  
  function updateName(name) {
    $.get('XXX',function (data) {
            var results = $.parseJSON(data);
            globalMatchName =String(results.data[0].first_name);
            }       
      );
      
      updatePerson(globalMatchName)
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for your answer. It works now :)